# How to install VLC Player on the original iPad (iOS 5.1.1)?

Tags: ios, ipad, vlc, compatibility

My friend has the original iPad that runs iOS 5.1.1 and can't be updated any further. Very few apps these days are compatible with that version of iOS. The new version of VLC in the App Store requires iOS 7.

What I thought I'd do is get an old version of the `.ipa` for VLC that's compatible with iOS 5.1.1. I have a computer with iTunes that I wonder if I can use to transfer it to the iPad.

1. Are some old versions of VLC compatible with iOS 5.1.1? If yes, what's the latest VLC version that's compatible?
2. Where can I get such `.ipa` files?
3. Do I have to jailbreak the iPad in order to install such downloaded files, or can I do it without jailbreaking?

Answer (score 1):

version 2.2.x is what you need.

The latest with 5.1 support according to wiki:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:IOS/#Feature_Overview

Download away! Vlc keeps all the different versions!
http://downloads.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-iOS/

No Jailbreak required.

Comment: for instructions on how to install the package, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160285/install-ipa-to-ipad-with-or-without-itunes

Comment: This actually didn't work, the app failed to install no matter which version I selected. But I managed to do it using [this method](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144924/153510).

Comment: Although the wiki saying 2.2.x is the latest compatible version for iOS 5.1, I managed to install 2.1.3 as the latest one. The 2.2.x keeps throwing errors on installing, saying not compatible...