# Old iPad - how to install apps without other device?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I recently got hold of an old iPad (gen 3, iOS 9.3.6) which works fine. The problem is that it refuses to install a sizable portion of apps, because the newest versions require higher iOS version. That's fine.

Two specific questions:

1. How do I tell if the app store still has the old version? ([people say it's up to the developer to remove the old versions from the app store](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/a4b5x6/spotify_netflix_etc_on_older_ipad/ebczy2m))
2. How do I install them if I do *not* own any other iOS device (iPhone or whatever). So the "App store | Purchased | Not on this iPad" trick won't work?

Would jailbreaking help?

Example apps I'd love to install: Spotify, Google Keep.

Comment: Keep in mind that an older unsupported iOS version is rather vulnerable and will never be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an old version iTunes on a computer you can download the current version there.  Once you go back to you iPad you can download the older version.

How to get the version iTunes you need.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320415/44531

The process[ ignore the blurb at the top which says you cannot ]:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144924/44531][2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144924/44531)

Comment: fyi. I've read where this older version of iTunes doesn't work on Catalina.

Comment: This has helped me a lot. To be precise:
1. old iTunes for *Microsoft Windows*
2. click download on apps there (disregarding the actual downloaded files)
3. on iPad's app store refer to apps installed on other devices