# Install old app version on iPad 1st generation iOS 5.1.1 (Windows 10, year 2018 question)

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, windows, install

I've just got first gen. iPad with iOS 5.1.1 and reset it to it's factory settings. Then I installed iTunes version 12.4.3.1 on my Windows 10 PC. Both iTunes and iPad are connected to same account and both are authorized. Now I can search for apps in the App Store.

I've already read tons of tutorials and advice how to install apps on outdated devices. I also checked this detailed answer [of Chad's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/how-to-install-apps-which-require-a-newer-version-of-ios-on-a-1st-gen-ipad?newreg=0889c16c1a0f4be2a241947ef0cffda0), but so far I find some app I need in App Store, I'm not more able to to do it. Install button on iTunes is now completely disabled.

[image]

And the same for any other app on the store.

Now I have now no clue how to handle it. I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's probably because the developers of those apps don't have older versions on the App Store anymore.  The developers determine what iOS versions they'll support.

Answer (score 1):

As the text in the graphic says, you need to open the App Store *on the iPad itself*, not through iTunes on your PC.

Comment: This is even a problem. iPad's AppStore itself doesn't let to install any apps becaus it let you install the latest version of app only. As hacks from another answers are suggesting, it's possible to install apps just after getting it from iTunes app store.

But, after long painfull tweaking and experinmenting, I've got how to do it. It works by me just with **iTunes 12.6.3**, but not with any other.

Comment: If remember correctly, apps applicable for the version of iOS on your iPad should be available in the App Store, but only if the app developer makes it available. Some app developers disable this and the app is only available in the latest version.