# How to download old versions of apps to old iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad 2. I hadn't used it for a while, but I'm trying to use it now. I was required to start from scratch with no apps or anything but many of the apps I had on there before are no longer compatible with such an old iOS. Most of them require 10 or higher which isn't an option for me. I am okay with downloading an older compatible version of the app, but that doesn't seem to be an option. I have seen a few others asking about this a few years back, but the solutions they got are no longer possible. How could I go about doing this?

EDIT:
I tried the response given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/how-to-install-apps-which-require-a-newer-version-of-ios-on-a-1st-gen-ipad), but the option to download from the app store on iTunes store seems to have been removed. I don't see an option to get around it.

Comment: Which specific questions have you looked at, what did you try, how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

If the app developer removed them from the App Store then you can't download them again.

It's up to the app developer to continue to offer older versions of their app, not Apple.

During the shift from 32-bit to 64-bit apps, developers had to change their old apps to comply with the architecture change in iOS.  Most did; some did not.